# Extracting XML data from NCLOB from XML with attributes in Oracle db

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

I am trying to extract values from XML data stored as NCLOB column in Oracle db table.

**xml structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/FAS/DOC/2011/v3.0b" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <record xmlns="http://example.com/FAS/DOC/2011/v3.0b">
    <pdate xmlns="http://example.com/FAS/DOC/2011/v3.0b">2014-05-15</pdate>
  </record>
</root>
```

**Query**

```
select EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(nclob_column),'/root/record/pdate','xmlns="http://example.com/FAS/DOC/2011/v3.0b"') pdate1,
       EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(nclob_column),'/root/record/pdate') pdate2
from   nclob_table
```

**Problem**

> The `pdate1` does return the value, but `pdate2` returns null. I
>   cannot use the third parameter of EXTRACTVALUE() to specify the xmlns
>   attribute value as that changes on every row/record. So I get the
>   value for one row but null for all others.

How do I extract the value without specifying the attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the namespace doesn't matter for selecting an element in this case, you can use `local-name()` to match element only by it's local name, ignoring the namespace :

```
select EXTRACTVALUE(
            XMLTYPE(nclob_column),
            '/*[local-name()="root"]/*[local-name()="record"]/*[local-name()="pdate"]'
        ) pdate
from   nclob_table
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c8f38/2)**